# Do all schools of BJJ come from the same root?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, history, schools

Do all schools of Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu (BJJ) come from the same original source? Or did some come down different path ways and hop on to the BJJ marketing wagon?

Answer (score 19):

Genuine Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu all stems from one man: Mitsuyo Maeda of Kodokan Judo. Maeda had numerous students the world over, and upon settling in Brazil, was featured in a circus there, where he was seen by Carlos Gracie, the eldest son of Gastao Gracie, a business partner of the circus there. Carlos was accepted as a student, passed on his training to his brothers, and Gracie Jiu-jitsu was born out of that training, adapted by the more naturally frail Helio Gracie... This is the best known form...

The other significant form is that of Luis França, who was also a student of Maeda's... Personally, I would not recognize the difference, but know the latter is recognizable by its unique forms of foot locks.

Comment: I've studied in RCJ Machado BJJ which branched from Carlos Gracie's Jiu-jitsu school. So the Machado BJJ also follows the Mitsuyo Maeda line. I don't know if any BJJ schools out that that teach BJJ that can't trace their linage back to Mitsuyo Maeda.

Comment: No legitimate ones, anyway ;)

Comment: all bjj came from Maeda, but it didn't all stem from the gracies after that.  there are several branches straight from Maeda, which a lot of people seem to forget/ not realize.   The Nova União team is a prime example of that.

Comment: @Patricia: You'll notice I made that distinction already, with the example of Luis França. I am quite sure there are many other minor forms; I only intended to show the most significant (currently) as being that of the Gracie lineage. Please let me know if I can make this more clear in the post.

Comment: your answer is good! i just wanted to make it a little more clear that not all bjj is from the gracies, a very common misconception.

Comment: In general, this answer is right. But I'm not sure about the specifics. That circus example doesn't match anything I've ever read before. Not that it matters much...

Comment: @Patricia how is Nova Uniao direct from Maeda? Pederneiras is a Carlson BB.

Comment: Wendall Alexander, the other 1/2 of the union http://www.bjjheroes.com/bjj-fighters/wendell-alexander

Answer (score 4):

There's Morganti Jiu Jitsu that is a Brazilian Jiu Jitsu style. It's usually not what is thought of when people say Brazilian Jiu Jitsu though, as Brazilian is a stand in for Gracie because Rorion sued his family members for using the name in the US.

Comment: According to [their website](http://morgantijujitsuklerksdorp.co.za/cms/history/), Morganti claims he learned jiu-jitsu his father, who learned from from one of the Ono Brothers (Yassuiti Ono or Oninho (Naoiti Ono)). If true this is indeed a separate lineage from those of the Gracie brothers.

Answer (score 2):

Roberto Pedreira's *Choque: The Untold Story of Jiu-Jitsu in Brazil 1856-1949: Volume 1* in one of its appendices contains a reconstructed hypothetical tree of the distinct lineages of judo/jiu-jitsu instructors in Brazil in the early 20th century, with a few caveats on reliability of information:

> <sup>**Appendix 3**</sup>
>
> ### Lineages
>
> The evidence for a lineage varied from reliable to questionable. Reliable evidence would be (authenticated) diplomas, photographs, and the like, and testimony from the teacher himself or his students based on their own first-hand experience. Questionable evidence would be self-promoting and uncorroborated or contested claims made many years after the alleged relationship, particularly when the individual had a documented history of lying. In short, the quality of evidence varied and in most cases lineages should be considered possible rather than certain.
>
> #### Kodokan Graduates in Brazil
>
> Conde Koma 前田光世 (1878-1941). Conde Koma’s main teacher was Sakujiro Yokoyama (who also taught Ito, Ono, and Satake). According to myth, Conde Koma’s style of fighting was aggressive. He would use kicks and punches to bring the opponent to the ground and then quickly finish with a “lock” or choke.<sup>1</sup> However, all of the available evidence clearly indicates that Conde Koma’s fights in Brazil were conducted strictly according to conventional jiu-jitsu rules. Kimonos were always worn and striking was never permitted (see main text for details). Conde Koma declined to fight capoeiras, whose game was striking.
>
> Geo Omori 大森瀼冶 (1892-1938). Earned his black belt [*faixa negra*] in 1909, when he was 17 from Kodokan, which he entered when he was 13, (1905). Omori’s main teacher was Conde Koma’s classmate Tokugoro Ito (whose teacher was also Conde Koma’s teacher, Sakujiro Yokoyama). Unlike Conde Koma, Geo Omori fought capoeiras and engaged in vale tudo fights. He also fought without kimono. However, he avoided boxers.
>
> Yassuiti Ono 小野安一 (1910-?). Ono’s main teacher was Kanemitsu Yaichibei ( 金光弥一市兵 衛 ) in 1922. Ono immigrated to Brazil in 1929, when he was 19. Originally from Kumamoto, Japan. Ono fought with and without kimono. He did not fight strikers.
>
> Takeo Yano 矢野武雄 (1909-?).<sup>2</sup> Like Yassuiti Ono and Masahiko Kimura, Yano was originally from Kumamoto, Japan (in fact, he attended the same middle school as Kimura). Yano fought with and without kimono. He did not fight strikers, although he challenged at least one boxer, and he fought numerous fake vale tudo “catch” fights.
>
> **Sada Miyako**
>   Mario Aleixo
>
> **Conde Koma**<sup>3</sup>
>   Bianor de Oliveira (Recife)
>   Donato Pires dos Reis (Belém)
>   Jacyntho Ferro (Belém)
>   Takeo Yano (Belém)<sup>4</sup>
>
> **Donato Pires dos Reis**
>   Carlos Gracie
>   George Gracie
>
> **Geo Omori**
>   Saburo Senda
>   Abrahão Gazal
>   Albino da Costa
>   Arthur Riquetto
>   Vincente Martins (student of Riquetto)
>   Carlos Equido
>   Gatti
>
> **Jose Barbosa**
>   Alberto Torre La Faria (Al Faria)
>   Roberto Coelho
>   Carlos Gracie
>   Benedicto Peres Campos
>   Arthur Miele (student of Peres)
>   Jose Cayat
>   Manoel Azevedo Maia
>   Ary Martini
>   Helio Gracie
>   Carlos Pereira
>   Adão Mayer
>   Antonio Marques
>
> **Oswaldo Gracie**
>   Mirando Neto
>   Jorge Saldanha
>   Dante Carvalho
>   Euripedes Dornelo
>
> **George Gracie**
>   Ricardo Nibbon
>   Camillo Hollanda
>
> **Takeo Yano**
>   Odemar Figueiredo
>   Eguti
>   Vincente Marques
>   Pinochio
>   Inhesil Marinho
>   Herminio de Oliveira
>   Antonio Marques
>   Waldyr Corbo
>
> **Gastão Gracie Filho**
>   Ennio Voss
>   Dr. Adhemar Barbosa
>
> **Yassuiti Ono**
>   Oninho (Naoiti Ono)
>   Luiz Tambucci
>   Braz Gomes I
>   Mazuko Tossio
>   Milton Ferreira
>   Udu Dorn
>   Vincente Lacerva
>   Jose Roberto Macedo Soares
>   Mario Shymada
>   Batiste Sarty
>   Salvador Cardia
>   Casimiro Tronscoco
>
> It is likely that all of the fighters who participated in preliminaries to Ono’s fights were his own students (refer to appendix 2).
>
> **Augusto Cordeiro**
>   Antonio Alfonso Alves
>   Floriano Cadeco
>   Luiz Alberto Moreira

> **Appendix 3 Notes**
>
> 1. [“*Seu estilo ao lutar era agressivo―usava chutes e soccos para lever o adversario ao solo, onde rapidamente o finalizava com uma chave ou um estrangulamento*”] (Gracie 2008, p. 37).
> 2. According to Nunes (2011, p. 62) Yano died in Belo Horizonte sometime in the 1980’s. Regrettably the sources Nunes cites do not seem to provide the relevant information about Yano.
> 3. In addition to the above, Carlos Gracie claimed to have learned from Conde Koma. H[is] claim was doubted by journalists who cared enough to have an opinion, and was denied by Koma’s student Donato Pires dos Reis. Oswaldo Gracie also claimed, although not often, to have learned directly from Conde Koma. Koma taught for many years in Belém. There is at least one photograph of him with seven students wearing modern judo *gi*s. A fact easily forgotten is that a Conde Koma lineage was not of any particular value until Rorion Gracie made it the starting point of his story in 1988. Before that, it is likely that anyone descending from Conde Koma would have sought affiliation within the judo community.
> 4. Takeo Yano spent some time with Conde Koma in Belém and was described as a “*discipulo*” implying that he was student of sorts. Yano had already graduated at the 3-dan level (after only one year) from the Kodokan before coming to Brazil [“*gradou-se, em doze mezes, com a titulo de faixa preta, 3. 0 grau*”] (*Correio Paulistano* 6-10-39).

Collapsing some of the connected trees, we have the following lineages for the Gracies:

- **Conde Koma**<sup>3</sup>

  - Donato Pires dos Reis (Belém)

    - Carlos Gracie
    - George Gracie

      - Ricardo Nibbon
      - Camillo Hollanda

- **Jose Barbosa**

  - Carlos Gracie
  - Helio Gracie

- **Oswaldo Gracie**

  - Mirando Neto
  - Jorge Saldanha
  - Dante Carvalho
  - Euripedes Dornelo

- **Gastão Gracie Filho**

  - Ennio Voss
  - Dr. Adhemar Barbosa